# Creating customer accounts without purchase

Tags: shopify

I have a requirement for a shopify site to use a "member model" where by the visitor can't access the website until they have signed up / logged in. Unfortunately, due to the workflow of shopify, the customer can only signup when they have bought something.

The API allows the creation of customer accounts, and was wondering if it could be used to create a customer account without the visitor actually buying anything and also to trigger the "invite" email so that its created as a usable account. Is this possible?

Or is there a workable solution to this? I fully understand and agree with shopify's workflow but it would be a nice option to have.

Regards,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Customer API deals with the creation and management of customer records, not Customer Accounts.

There is no way to create customer accounts programatically at this time.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. Can you explain the difference between a customer "record" and a customer "account". Surely by creating a customer record they are getting an account in the shop? Or is the customer record used for something else?

Would it be possible to create the customer "record" and then the administrator send the "invite" email - or is the record not available to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. In case it might help, here's how you can add customer records using the PHP API adapter:

```
<?php
require 'shopify.php';
$shopify = shopify_api_client($shops_myshopify_domain, NULL, $api_key, $password, true);

try
{

    $newCustomer = array
    (
        "customer" => array
        (
            "first_name"    => $_POST['first_name'],
            "last_name"     => $_POST['last_name'],
            "email"         => $_POST['email']
        )
    );

    try
    {
        $addCustomer = $shopify('POST', '/admin/customers.json', $newCustomer, $response_headers);          
    }
    catch (ShopifyApiException $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
    }

}
catch (ShopifyApiException $e)
{
    print_r($e->getInfo());
}
catch (ShopifyCurlException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

This still leaves you with the activation headache. AFAIK Shopify doesn't offer anything in their API to automate the sending of activation emails.

Perhaps something like http://mechanize.rubyforge.org could handle the repetitive Send Activation stuff, not sure.